# Return different data upon non matching where clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm running the following query on BigQuery:

```
WITH allTables AS ( 
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `dataset1.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406'

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `dataset2.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406'
) 
SELECT 
  app AS target,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170406')) AS datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```

The final query will be a lot larger than this but this is just a simple example. The issue I'm having is that if the where condition is not met, nothing will be returned. I want to change this query so that when the where is not met, it will return different data. Is there a way to do this within BigQuery? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What data do you want it to return when the where condition is not met?

Comment: Basically, app, 0 and timestamp. All the select values from the select on `allTables` except datapoint_value should be 0.

Comment: assume no matches found at all  - can  you provide example of output you need?! just above comment is not enough (at least for me) to understand what you mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up not needing to do this for my project, instead I'm simply running a single insert for the tables per day and then updating on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but using the where conditions as a case statement on app and users might do the trick. Manually inserting the day as timestamp and parsing that would ensure you get data for each subquery.

```
WITH allTables AS ( 
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406' 
         OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406' 
         THEN CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) 
         ELSE NULL END AS app,
    CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406' 
         OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406' 
         THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ELSE NULL END AS users,
    '20170406' as timestamp
  FROM `dataset1.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event   
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406' 
         OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406' 
         THEN CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) 
         ELSE NULL END AS app,
    CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406' 
         OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406' 
         THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id 
         ELSE NULL END AS users,
    '20170406' as timestamp
  FROM `dataset2.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
) 
SELECT 
  app AS target,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', timestamp)) AS datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```